# Pattern-defeating Quicksort vs Timsort?

Tags: sorting, quicksort, mergesort, timsort

I recently came across pattern-defeating quicksort (pdqsort).
https://github.com/orlp/pdqsort
https://github.com/stjepang/pdqsort

However, I haven't been able to find any extensive study that profiles pdqsort, and compares it against the other popular Timsort. Does anyone know how these 2 algorithms fare against each other? Is there any paper around? Thanks.

Comment: There is already benchmark data from the first link. std::stable_sort is faster in two cases, "pipe organ" and "push front". In X86-X64 in 64 bit mode with 16 registers, I find a  4 way merge sort with no heap to be as fast or a bit faster than minimal quicksort with no fall back to heap sort with random data.